# Adding additional items to dictionary

Tags: swift

Would like to add John together with Peter in this combination:

```
var myData0: [String: String] = ["Item": "Milk", "Description": "Milk is white", "DrinksMilk": "Peter"]
myData0["DrinksMilk"] = "John"
println(myData0)
```

Println gives only John back instead Peter AND John. Is there a way to add John without overwriting Peter?

Comment: Make your array of type `[String: AnyObject]` and assign an array of values to the key where you want multiple values so it'll look like `["Item": "Milk", "DrinksMilk" : ["John", "Peter"]]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep a string value of dictionary, you can do like that

```
var myData0: [String: String] = ["Item": "Milk", "Description": "Milk is white", "DrinksMilk": "Peter"]
myData0["DrinksMilk"] = myData0["DrinksMilk"]! + ", John"
println(myData0)
```

If not, you can change the type of dictionary value to AnyObject like that :

```
 var myData0: [String: AnyObject] = ["Item": "Milk", "Description": "Milk is white", "DrinksMilk": "Peter"]
myData0["DrinksMilk"] = [myData0["DrinksMilk"]!, "John"]
println(myData0)
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are attempting to encode a data type into a dictionary.  A better approach, not knowing anything more about your specific problem, is to define a class for this:

```
class Drink {
  var name:String
  var desc:String
  var drinkers:[Person]
  // ...
  func addDrinker (person:Person) {
   drinkers.append(person)
  }
}
```

You've declared your dictionary to hold values of type `String` but, as you describe, now you want the dictionary values to be `String` or `Array`.  The common type of these type value types is `Any` (it can be `AnyObject` if you've imported Foundation; but that is a Swift anomaly).  You will then need to 'fight' the type system to coerce the "DrinksMilk" field as a modifiable array and to add "John".

```
// First extract `"DrinksMilk"` and force it to a mutating array:
var drinkers:[String] = myData0["DrinksMilk"]! as [String]

// Add the new drinker
drinkers.append("John")

// Reassign back into data
myData0["DrinksMilk"] = drinkers
```

Comment: Wow, that was a wasted effort.  Good luck.